# Random flash object page PHP

Tags: php, flash, web

```
FIXED!
Feel free to use my code, no need to cite my work. There was no problem, just that the image size was too small and some weren't showing up. duh.

I will change the size from 100px to 500px for anyone who wants to use this code.

Have fun
```

I'm trying to use some open code that's available on the internet to make a random flash generator.

The orignal code:

```
<?php
$imglist='';
//$img_folder is the variable that holds the path to the swf files.
// see that you dont forget about the "/" at the end
$img_folder = "images/";
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000);
//use the directory class
$imgs = dir($img_folder);
//read all files from the directory, ad them to a list
while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
if (eregi("swf", $file))
$imglist .= "$file ";
} closedir($imgs->handle);
//put all images into an array
$imglist = explode(" ", $imglist);
$no = sizeof($imglist)-2;
//generate a random number between 0 and the number of images
$random = mt_rand(0, $no);
$image = $imglist[$random];
//display random swf
echo '<embed src="'.$img_folder.$image.'" quality="high"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100"
height="100"></embed>';
?>
```

My modified code:

```
<?php
$imglist='';
//$img_folder is the variable that holds the path to the swf files.
// see that you dont forget about the "/" at the end
$img_folder = "../files/flash/";
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000);
//use the directory class
$imgs = dir($img_folder);
//read all files from the directory, ad them to a list
while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
if (preg_match("/(swf)/i", $file))
$imglist .= "$file ";
} closedir($imgs->handle);
//put all images into an array
$imglist = explode(" ", $imglist);
$no = sizeof($imglist)-2;
//generate a random number between 0 and the number of images
$random = mt_rand(0, $no);
$image = $imglist[$random];
//display random swf
echo '<embed src="'.$img_folder.$image.'" quality="high"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"
height="500"></embed>';
?>
```

I was at first having problems with ergi on line 11, I was told to replace it with preg and I went through and figured that out.

I loaded up my random page, (http://www.nsgaming.us/random/) and it flashed for a fraction of a second a random flash object I had in the folder but now it just shows nothing.

help please?

my index shows as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <?php 
    include("../menu.php");
    include_once('random2.php');
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>
<p>This is the random page.</p>
<p>I am planning on having random flash objects load here but still working on it.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind I am new to moderate at web design, HTML and PHP.
If you could try and not yell at me for doing something stupid which is probably what happened.

Comment: I got `src="../files/flash/of"` and `src="../files/flash/Mario"` from 2 pages, don't think this is what you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
if (preg_match("/(swf)/i", $file))
```

try

```
if (preg_match("/\.swf$/i", $file))
```

Also the following line is going to break your code if any filename has space in your filename.

```
$imglist = explode(" ", $imglist);
```

Instead of

```
while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
    if (preg_match("/(swf)/i", $file))
    $imglist .= "$file ";
} closedir($imgs->handle);
//put all images into an array
$imglist = explode(" ", $imglist);
```

The following code will help you serve the filenames with spaces also. This will also exclude the two dot directories.

```
$imglist=array();
while (false !== ($file = $imgs->read())) {
  if (($file==".")||($file=="..")) continue;
  if (preg_match("/\.swf$/i", $file))
  $imglist[]= $file;
} $imgs->close();
```

Comment: I fixed the first one, not sure what that did but the second one wasn't working so well, (I did however notice my code was taking single words out of files with spaces, like 'and' or 'the' and not providing anything. So I just made sure everything had underscores.

Comment: I wrongly used `$imglist[]= "$file ";` instead of `$imglist[]= $file;`. fixed it. Instead of adding the files to a string with a space at end and then splitting using space as delimiter, i am directly adding the file to the array (less code and won't break with filenames with space in them).

Answer (score 1):

The flash objects are returning 404.

One of them actually works.

http://www.nsgaming.us/files/flash/anon_partyhard007.swf

Based on this, I think you might be looking at the wrong files folder. I'm assuming you have a public files folder, and then a files folder one level below root?

Perhaps this might work better.

```
$img_folder = "./files/flash/";
```

Comment: It definitely doesn't work with ./ opposed to ../

I think some of the flash files may be corrupt because I downloaded one that I inspected element of the blank (where it should be) and it still didn't load after downloading it.